# Adding custom modules to activities button

Tags: sugarcrm

I have an installation of Sugar 6.5. I'v created a custom module and created the relationship with Opportunities and I'm seeing it correctly as a panel at the bottom of the Opportunity.

I want to add it as an Activity to the "Create Task/Schedule Meeting/Log a call" button in the Activities panel.

I've tried to create a relationship with Activities but this doesn't seem to do it either. I've also looked through the dropdowns list and can't find this button/dropdown at all.

Is it possible to add options to this activity dropdown button?